# Mp3 Play from Stream on C#

Tags: c#, mp3, audio-player

I have music urls. Urls like http://site.com/audio.mp3 . I want play this file online, like youtube. Do you know a class or code can do this ?

Comment: On a web site or in a desktop application?

Comment: So you want to stream your music online to other people? You mean a radio?

Comment: I dont want stream music. I want PLAY mp3 files from url or stream. Like youtube player. But it is on desktop application.

Comment: If it's a desktop application, you shouldn't have tagged it [tag:asp.net] or [tag:html]. *tags removed*

Comment: "I want play this file online, like youtube." makes it sound like you want to "play it online", "like youtube"; not on your desktop.  You need to word your problem and specs better.

Comment: I wanna play mp3 file from url. Like flash youtube player, but not flash, in c# on desktop.

Sorry, I know bit of english.

Comment: Yes the class is called NAudio, I asked a similar question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704731/how-to-play-mp3-file-from-online-resources-in-c/11704899#11704899